# Setting variables in a different class in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, class, nsstring

I'm trying to learn how to set variables for different classes using one main data class.

Here's a diagram of of what I would like to do and the code from my project:
[image]

ClassA

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassA : NSObject {
    NSString *stringA;
    NSString *stringB;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *stringA;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *stringB;

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *textA;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *textB;

- (IBAction)displayStrings:(id)sender;

@end

#import "ClassA.h"

@implementation ClassA

@synthesize stringA, stringB, textA, textB;

- (IBAction)displayStrings:(id)sender {
    [textA setStringValue:stringA];
    [textB setStringValue:stringB];
}

@end
```

Class X

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassX : NSObject {
    NSMutableString *stringX;
}

- (void)theVariables:(id)sender;

@end

#import "ClassX.h"
#import "ClassA.h"

@implementation ClassX

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self theVariables:self];
}

- (void)theVariables:(id)sender {
    stringX = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    ClassA *clssA = [[ClassA alloc] init];

    [stringX setString:@"stringX for stringA"];
    [clssA setStringA:stringX];

    [stringX setString:@"stringX for stringB"];
    [clssA setStringB:stringX];
}

@end
```

No errors show up in the code, but when I run the program I am receiving an error about "Invalid parameter not satisfying: aString". It looks like the setStringValue for the IBOutlet is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please include the errors in your question, and explain how the actual results differ from your expected results.

Comment: That error points to the line(s) inside `displayStrings:`?

Comment: @JacquesCousteau So does that mean my IBOutlets in interface builder are connected wrong? I connected them the same way I always have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing the error you mention, but as far as I can tell from your code, the main problem is this line:

```
ClassA *clssA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
```

You must have an instance of `ClassA` in your xib, which is connected to text fields and a button. That object in the xib is a real object, and if you just create another instance of `ClassA` somewhere in your code, you have an entirely different object that has no connection to the one that's in your xib.

You need to make sure of/change two things. First, there needs to be an instance of `ClassX` in your xib. Second, `ClassX` needs an outlet to a `ClassA` instance:

```
@class ClassA;    // Declare ClassA so you can use it below

@interface ClassX : NSObject

@property (weak) IBOutlet ClassA * theClassAInstance;

- (void)theVariables:(id)sender;

@end
```

Which should then be connected in the xib file. Then, in `theVariables:`, you just use that outlet instead of creating a new instance of `ClassA`: `[[self theClassAInstance] setStringA:@"stringX for stringA"];`

---

Three points of style:

First, you should be importing Cocoa.h: `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` instead of Foundation.h in any class that touches the GUI (`ClassA` in this case). That's where stuff like `NSTextField` is defined. It works anyways because Cocoa.h is imported via your .pch file, but it's best to be explicit.

Second, creating a mutable string and changing its value to two different literal strings doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Just use the literals directly: `[clssA setStringA:@"stringX for stringA"];`

Third, You don't need to declare the instance variables separately; `@synthesize` creates them for you, and it is now the recommended practice to *not* declare them:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *stringA;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *stringB;

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *textA;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *textB;

- (IBAction)displayStrings:(id)sender;

@end
```

Last (four points!), you should really be accessing the values of `stringA` and `stringB` in `ClassA` via the property: `[textA setStringValue:[self stringA]];`

Comment: Hallelujah - It works! I've been going crazy trying to figure this out.

Comment: One more thing, how can I implement the `displayStrings:` in `ClassA` after the application starts? I tried using `awakeFromNib` but I get that same error again.

Comment: Figured out that I can call the methods in ClassA too! I can use the following in ClassX by `[[self theClassA] displayStrings:sender];` Sweet, this takes care of my previous comment.